# HREF within an IFrame with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to get the href value within an iframe:

```
var jfrm = $('#MyIFrame').contents()
```

gets me the contents of the frame fine

In the frame, I have multiple HREF elements, and I need to get one.  They are as such:

```
<a href="javascript:SomeFunc(3,'Value');func2(parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4)">
```

I know I need the HREF with the number 3, and from that I need to get the string value of parm4.

It is not necessarily the first HREF element in the frame.  The 3 param in SomeFunc() will be unique though, so I can key off of that.

TIA

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Please post the code you've already tried and any errors or other relevant data.  That will help other users answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get `"SomeFunc(3,'Value')"` and `'parm4'` given an element on the page like this:

`<a href="javascript:SomeFunc(3,'Value');func2(parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4)">`

Assuming the element for which you want href information is the first `<a>` on the page, you can generate this array: `['javascript:SomeFunc(3,'Value')','func2(parm1, parm2, parm3, parm4)']`

like this:

```
var hrefs=$('a').first().attr('href').split(';');
```

To get a clean version of the first item, do:

```
var firstItem=hrefs[0].replace('javascript:','');
```

which will get you: `"SomeFunc(3,'Value')"`

To get the value of the last parameter of the last function, do:

```
var params=hrefs[hrefs.length-1].split(',');
var lastParam=params[params.length-1].replace(')','').trim();
```

That will get you `'parm4'`